# Application is launched in wrong way on os x

Tags: python, macos, subprocess, launchd

I start application within python using subprocess module, so this application appears in Activity Monitor utility under roots "launchd.

```
cmd = "/usr/bin/sudo -H -u "+ self.getCurrentUserName() + "-P" + +os.path.join(dir, app) + app_args
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
```

When application is started manually via Terminal it works ok and it appears under current users "launchd". 
Is it possible to launch applications under current users "launchd" within python?

I'm running OS X 10.6.

Answer (score 1):

When you run a command as sudo, it will always show up as belonging to root, that is what sudo does...

--Dave

Comment: Actually, using the `-u` flag you can run command as any other user (not only root). And that is the case in the OP's example.